# Please tell me what movies are featured here?

Tags: discussion

Can anyone please tell me what are the names of these movies that are featured here?
This image has posters or events from famous movies. I know the rest of the movies or shows but unable to identify marked movies.
Thanks in advanced.
Heres the image:

[image]